# submit on radio change + prevent page reload, not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, addeventlistener

I want to submit an HTML form when a radio button gets checked, where the submit event calls a JS function to prevent a page reload (plus some other stuff).

The solution below works on Chrome, but doesn't work on Firefox. I've found a lot of answers on submitting an HTML form on a radio check, but none of the solutions I've found work on Firefox. Firefox always gives me the following warning:

```
Form submission via untrusted submit event is deprecated and will be removed at a future date.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" onchange="this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" onchange="this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" onchange="this.form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));">
    </form>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", submitExercise);

        function submitExercise(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("test");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call the ***submitExcercise()*** method with ***event*** as parameter when radio button is changed.

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" onchange="submitExercise(event)">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" onchange="submitExercise(event)">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" onchange="submitExercise(event)">
</form>
<script>
  function submitExercise(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
  }
</script>
```

OR

call ***submitExcercise()*** when the form element is changed, this will trigger if any child element is changed.

```
<form id="form" onchange="submitExercise(event)">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3">
</form>
<script>
  function submitExercise(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Dunno why I didn't realize the form doesnt actually need to submit... Great call! Thx!